# How to reverse jQuery Reel autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-reel

I'm using jQuery Reel to show a 360 product view, doing something like this:

```
$('img.one').reel({
    image: 'http://jquery.vostrel.cz/demo/rc-reel.jpg',
    frames: 35,
    speed: 0.4
});
```

I'd like to have it autoplay in reverse (right-to-left, rather than the default left-to-right), but I *don't* want to change the way the dragging and indicator work (which is what `cw: true` does -- so I can't use that).

### What I've tried

The option `cw: true` does make it play in reverse, but the dragging and indicator are now backwards from the way they should be.

The option `inversed: true` seems like it would do exactly what I'm looking for, but so far as I can tell, it doesn't change anything.

Setting the `speed` option to a negative value (i.e. `speed: -0.4`) seems to act the same as setting it to a positive value (it doesn't change anything).

Even reversing the order of the images (I'm using an image list rather than a sprite) doesn't help, since that's essentially exactly the same as using `cw: true`, so the dragging and indicator are still backwards when doing that.  Combining reversed order image list with `cw: true` is the same as using no options at all, and again, `inversed: true` appears to have no effect in this case as well.

Check out [this JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwsH6/) to see my test case.
(It's using a sprite rather than an image list, but it behaves the same as an image list in all my tests.)

I've tested with both Reel 1.2.1 and 1.3.

---

How do I get the reel to autoplay in reverse, while still maintaining the drag and indicator directions?

Comment: you can try with backwards like this [http://jsfiddle.net/JwsH6/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/JwsH6/3/)

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm.  It's too bad there isn't just a regular config option that can do the same thing though.

Comment: you may need to change the code in jquery.reel.js so it can set the backwards property or set it to true by default